# Ruby Variable Binding Inside Loops

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need to loop through an aliases hash, and transform the header array by assigning it values from the aliases hash in a Ruby class.

I can't seem to transform the header array and then have it available after the loop.

How do I transform the header array so it is available for use after the loop?

```
 header = ["City", "State"]

 aliases = {"City"=>"Las Vegas", "State"=>"Nevada"}

 aliases.each do |k,v|
   header.each do |s|   
     if s == k then
       s = v            
     end
   end
 end

 puts header
```

Comment: This code runs fine. "sees" everything it should see (but you assert that it doesn't).

Comment: You're correct, I think the issue may be that `s=v` does not change the header.

Comment: In future, don't be in such a rush to select an answer! Quick selections may discourage other answers, and by waiting awhile (at least a couple of hours, say) readers may point out weaknesses in answers that you may not have thought of. Note that you can always change your selection. Incidentally, I see no reason for the Rails tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
header = ["City", "State"]

 aliases = {"City"=>"Las Vegas", "State"=>"Nevada"}

 aliases.each do |k,v|
   header.each do |s|   #doesn't see header variable
     if s == k 
      header[header.index(s)] = v            #doesn't see v variable
     end
   end
 end

 puts header
```

Don't know if I got it right, think it's what you're looking for. Good luck!

EDIT: I would still simplify it like this:

```
header = ["City", "State"]

aliases = {"City"=>"Las Vegas", "State"=>"Nevada"}

header.each do |s|
  aliases.select{|k,v| k==s}.each do |k,v|
    header[header.index(s)] = v
  end
end
puts header
```

Comment: Thanks, that works. It looks like header was getting looped over but the values did not change with my code. Indexing it solves the issue

Comment: you call that a _simplification_? :) `header.map! {|s| aliases[s] }`

Comment: `header = aliases.values_at(*header)`

Comment: OP would do well to learn to avoid mutating stuff like this. Suddenly `header` is not a header (does not contain header-y values). Makes code impossible to read.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Or maybe just `aliases.values`.

Comment: @StefanPochmann: for _this_ use case, sure. I can easily imagine `aliases` mapping contain some "extra" fields.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev thanks for the tips, but don't need to be so arrogant =)

Comment: @RonanLopes: I wasn't. That snippet is _objectively_ more complex than the one before. If you don't mind, what exactly is _simpler_ about it? :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev it's a shorter syntax. Nothing more than that

Comment: @SergioTulentsev And I can easily imagine `aliases` *missing* some fields. Then yours wouldn't work that well, either. But I can also imagine that their example is indeed representative, that they do have a perfect match there. (Really if that wasn't the case, then the example shouldn't be like that.)

Comment: @RonanLopes: shorter, maybe. It's called "more terse", not "simpler". Big difference! :)

Comment: @StefanPochmann: I can also easily imagine that fields are the same, but the _order_  between header and mapping is different. Ruby hashes being ordered should not be relied on (too much), IMHO. Lots of speculation in this thread. :)

Comment: @RonanLopes Looks like I missed the party here. I believe your solution is better as because in the case the aliases hash is missing values it returns the original value of the array while Sergio's solution returns nil.

Comment: @HoosierCoder yeah, I actually didn't see that... so it will depends on your needs. If you wanna get only the ones that matches, his solution will be better =)